# Get Group Product Path(URL) from Single Product ID

Tags: product, url, grouped-products

Given that I already have the **single** product id, was it possible to get it's grouped product url that has the certain single product id that I got?

For example,

I got a single product id of **11**

Group_Product_1

1. Single1 (product id = 10)
2. Single2 (product id = 11)
3. Single3 (product id = 12)

Group_Product_2

1. Single4 (product id = 13)
2. Single5 (product id = 14)
3. Single6 (product id = 15)

What I want to happen is get the GROUP PRODUCT URL that has a single product id of **11**

Well I have this certain **sample** code,

```
$singleId = 11;

//Check if product type is grouped
if ($_product->getTypeId() == Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type::TYPE_GROUPED) {

    //Get group product's id from single product's id
    $parentId = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_type_grouped')->getParentIdsByChild($singleId);

    $groupProduct = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($parentId); 
    $groupPath = $groupProduct->getProductUrl();

    echo $groupPath;
}
```

But what I'm getting is...

mysite.com/catalog/product/view/category/312

It does redirect me to somewhere that page does not exist (page 404)

Any solution for this stuff?

Answer (score 1):

I think that the problem you are having is that the simple product will have the type `simple` and not `grouped`. If you update your code to not check type but if the returned parentids array is empty then your code should work as desired.

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($singleId);
$parentIds = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_type_grouped')->getParentIdsByChild($product->getId());
foreach($parentIds as $parentId) {
    $groupProduct = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($parentId);
    $groupPath = $groupProduct->getProductUrl();

    echo $groupPath;
}
```